# configuration of log4net

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I want to use log4net in my application in C#.

I made configuration file for log4net: `ConsoleTest.exe.log4net` and set in the properties option to copy to the destination folder:

```xml
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
</configSections>
<log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newlineExtra Info: %property{testProperty}%newline%exception" />
        </layout>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
            <levelMin value="INFO" />
            <levelMax value="FATAL" />
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="mylogfile.txt"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
    <stringToMatch value="test"/>
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
    <stringToMatch value="error"/>
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="Log4NetTest.OtherClass">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </logger>
</log4net>
```

In the project in Visual Studio 2012, in properties, in file `AssemblyInfo.cs` I added:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(
ConfigFile = "ConsoleTest.exe.log4net", Watch = true)]
```

In the class where I want to log I added:

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

but when I write in this class:

```
log.Debug("This is a DEBUG level message. The most VERBOSE level.");
log.Info("Extended information, with higher importance than the Debug call");
log.Warn("An unexpected but recoverable situation occurred");
```

I don't get anything at output :(

Where is a problem ?

**Edit:**
Is my configuration file correct?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: I wrote [this document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v8fycyEc2JYdcHQ2tgVd_RH6aJySwoAC4Ug_pgNzqIE/edit?usp=sharing) about how to setup Log4Net which you might find useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean with "output"?

Is the log file created at all? Your filters exclude all logging that doesn't contain 'test' or 'error', but a zero-length file should be created. Remove the filter elements to fix this.

Your console and trace loggers will not receive anything using this configuration. If you want to see console output, add <appender-ref ref="ConsoleLogger" /> to your root element.

Not an error, but you only need the log4net section when using a separate file for log4net configuration. Also check the basics: is your configuration file part of the build output?

Comment: "output" mean window in Visul Studio. ok, i understend now. I have to add `<appender-ref ref="TraceAppender" />` to root element. And file logging works good. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
   <stringToMatch value="test"/>
 </filter>
 <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
    <stringToMatch value="error"/>
  </filter>
 <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
```

These lines mean you will only log messages which contain either **test** or **error**.

You also look to be missing a closing tag for configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on the logging?
We have the following line in our Global.asax

```
 log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Comment: i don't have `Global.asax` file:( I add in `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, it's looks similar:

`[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(
ConfigFile = "ConsoleTest.exe.log4net", Watch = true)]`